# How to set width depends on height of Ext.panel.Panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a panel with some textfields. I don't set height but I need keep 16:9 ratio. Size needs to be change depends on height. But I cant find where I can set width.

Comment: can you please add some code so we can work on it? diffucult to understand what really you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in listeners. Example for your problem solution here:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kve

Comment: Thank you, Andrew it helps, I just use panel.setWidth()